# Python Regular Expression not working for Gmail body

Tags: python, regex, zapier

I am trying to extract a name, phone number, and email from a GMAIL Email body using python regular expression and Zapier keeps saying no results found.

Here is the Body of the Email:

```
*****************************************************************
You received a new message from your online store's contact form.
*****************************************************************
Name:
-----
James Bacon
Phone:
------
3171234567
Email:
------
jamesb1234@gmail.com
Intentions:
-----------
my family
```

Here is my regular expression:

`Name:\n-----\n(.*)\n`

The Regex101.com says it found a match just fine, but Zapier keeps saying no results found.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you update your question to include the input you're sending to zapier?

Comment: I tried it on my end and it worked fine: https://zappy.zapier.com/42D672BE-D5D7-4B14-ACDE-5DCC2DF8F762.png -> https://zappy.zapier.com/AA164FB2-CC66-4ABD-A76A-BF605430839C.png

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern `(Name|Phone|Email):.*?\n([^\n\-]+)\n(?=^.*?:)` ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/giSAYq/1)):

```
data = '''*****************************************************************
You received a new message from your online store's contact form.
*****************************************************************
Name:
-----
James Bacon
Phone:
------
3171234567
Email:
------
jamesb1234@gmail.com
Intentions:
-----------
my family'''

import re

name = re.findall(r'Name:.*?\n([^\n\-]+)\n(?=^.*?:)', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)
phone = re.findall(r'Phone:.*?\n([^\n\-]+)\n(?=^.*?:)', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)
email = re.findall(r'Email:.*?\n([^\n\-]+)\n(?=^.*?:)', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)

print(name)
print(phone)
print(email)
```

Prints:

```
['James Bacon']
['3171234567']
['jamesb1234@gmail.com']
```

Or one line:

```
g = re.findall(r'(Name|Phone|Email):.*?\n([^\n\-]+)\n(?=^.*?:)', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)
print(g)
```

Prints:

```
[('Name', 'James Bacon'), ('Phone', '3171234567'), ('Email', 'jamesb1234@gmail.com')]
```

This can be feed to `dict`:

```
d = dict(re.findall(r'(Name|Phone|Email):.*?\n([^\n\-]+)\n(?=^.*?:)', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'Name': 'James Bacon', 'Phone': '3171234567', 'Email': 'jamesb1234@gmail.com'}
```